# Snowflake Ext Stage location (EG. AWS s3) has nested folders with date info in the folder names

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have external stage organized as follows:

s3://finance/credits

```
/Week_2022_0601_0607
     file01.json
     file02.json
/Week_2022_0608_0615
     file01.json
     file02.json
     file03.json
etc...  New folders will get added each week
```

Can I define my storage_location property for my external stage as:

"s3://finance/credits/./*.json"

so that in my COPY INTO... code, snowflake will automatically traverse the nested  "date info" related folder and load all the files?  Since new folders will be added each week, I cannot create multiple hard-coded folders in the stage storage_location path for the stage.

This really applies to any path  - COPY INTO with or without using a Stage.

Comment: you normally define the URL of the CREATE STAGE as the `url = 's3://mybucket/finance/credits/'` and leave the json match to the COPY INTO command.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Snowflake Citibike Lab](https://s3.amazonaws.com/snowflake-workshop-lab/Snowflake_free_trial_LabGuide.pdf)

You create a stage like:

```
create stage citibike.public.citibike_trips 
    url = 's3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips';
```

a file format like:

```
create file format citibike.public.csv type = csv 
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' 
    NULL_IF = ('\\N', '');
```

then load the files like:

```
copy into trips 
    from @citibike_trips 
    file_format = csv 
    PATTERN= '.*trips_.*csv.gz';
```

anyways, a S3 Object name is not a PATH, it is just a string, which looks like a path, and thus when you match the path, ALL files that match are returned.

This point should be strongly considered as as your set of files builds up, you can start have millions of files in S3, and that full list will be transferred to Snowflake on each operation.

Anyways Snowfalke keeps a list of the files loaded in the last 2 weeks and does not reload these if they have not changed. Files older than 2 weeks are assumed not changed and ignored.

The standard advice is to track a high water mark, and have you folder/path hierarchical `year-month-week/day` so you can use progressive path filters, to reduce the LIST size transfer.

Comment: Simeon, following your example, I see that you have an ending folder of citibike-trips.  So I am not seeing a nested structure in your example.  However, you later give reference to using a hierarchical structure of year-month-week-day, but not how that fits into the citi-bike-trips folder.  In your PATTERN= '.*trips_.*csv.gz'; for the stage, are you saying that files inside folders named 2022-Week1-trips and 2022-Week2-trips and 2022-Week3-trips would automatically be traversed using that pattern?  Otherwise, without an example with a structure like mine, I am not understanding.

Comment: I tested this, and creating a stage referencing the desired root folder, in my case, s3://finance/credits is all that is needed.  The nested folders above were auto traversed when COPY INTO...from @<stage> was executed.  All files within the nested folders were ingested into snowflake.  So, looks like the property pattern=<desired pattern> is ONLY used to filter which files (not folders) get ingested?  Simeon seems to indicate that I can also "filter" the path.  I still do not see how to do that if I wanted to 
"... so you can use progressive path filters, to reduce the LIST size transfer."

Comment: The path part has to be automated in an external tooling. But if you know you have loaded all of the “2022/07_jul/“ files you might use “2033/08.*\.csv” as the file match. Again to repeat. There is no folders. It is just one long file name. The two filters are just regular expressions match a string. The happens to look like a path.

Comment: The citibike example SQL was stuff I had lying around with the PATH and FILTER seperated, and I knew worked. The description of "having hierarches" was from my old work setup, and we used node.js code to build the correct filter to be as tight as possible to avoid loading to many files. aka some of my answer story, some is example, not all story is demo'ed in code,